# How do I install Git for Windows to a specific directory?

Tags: windows, git

I want to install Git for Windows on my working machine. The problem is I don't have the necessary permissions in Program Files and noone will grant me these (company policy). Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this version:

#### Git Portable

https://github.com/sheabunge/GitPortable

> Git Portable is a portable version of Git for Windows packaged in PortableApps.com Format.

```
# ... Copy the GitPortable directory from this repository to a location of your choice.
```

Comment: GitPortable installer has a very old git binary, follow this instruction https://github.com/sheabunge/GitPortable/issues/28 to update git binaries on top of the existing gitportable folder.